# Background didn't be draw in case of different corner?

Tags: android

I want create a view with different corners , the shape's xml is following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="#01A2EA" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
    android:radius="30dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
    android:topRightRadius="30dp" />

</shape>
```

It performs good with blue background, but after I changed two of four corner radius like:

```
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
    android:radius="30dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
```

It lost its backgound color and I can see nothing.

The API document says:

> Note: Every corner must (initially) be provided a corner radius greater than 1, or else no corners are rounded. If you want specific corners to not be rounded, a work-around is to use android:radius to set a default corner radius greater than 1, but then override each and every corner with the values you really want, providing zero ("0dp") where you don't want rounded corners.

**But it seems dosen't work correctly with background ?**

Comment: try removing android:radius="30dp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right there is a bug, But you can resolve it like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#01A2EA" />

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0.1dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0.1dp"/>
</shape>
```

**NOTE :**

This may not reflect at design time. So please run the code to see effect.

Answer (score 1):

Use following instead.

```
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="30dp" />
```

Comment: your code is also run correctly on real devices :-)